# How to convert 2d numpy array into binary indicator matrix for max value

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, machine-learning

assuming I have a 2d numpy array indicating probabilities for m samples in n classes (probabilities sum to 1 for each sample).

Assuming each sample can only be in one category, I want to create a new array with the same shape as the original, but with only binary values indicating which class had the highest probability.

Example:

```
[[0.2, 0.3, 0.5], [0.7, 0.1, 0.1]]
```

should be converted to:

```
[[0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0]]
```

It seems amax already does almost what I want, but instead of the indices I want an indicator matrix as descrived above.

Seems simple, but somehow I can't figure it out using standard numpy functions. I could use regular python loops of course, but it seems there should be a simpler way.

In case multiple classes have the same probability, I would prefer a solution which only selects one of the classes (I don't care which in this case).

Thanks!

Comment: No, it is unlikely they will have exactly the same value. I only want one category to be chosen, I don't really care which one in this case.

Comment: Added, thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
In [112]: a
Out[112]: 
array([[ 0.2,  0.3,  0.5],
       [ 0.7,  0.1,  0.1]])

In [113]: a == a.max(axis=1, keepdims=True)
Out[113]: 
array([[False, False,  True],
       [ True, False, False]], dtype=bool)

In [114]: (a == a.max(axis=1, keepdims=True)).astype(int)
Out[114]: 
array([[0, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 0]])
```

(But this will give a True value for *each* occurrence of the maximum in a row.  See Divakar's answer for a nice way to select just the first occurrence of the maximum.)

Comment: I don't think this works for numpy arrays though... I didn't see a keepdims parameter in their max function.

Comment: `a` is a numpy array. Which version of numpy are you using?

Comment: I'm using version 1.10.4.

Comment: Then `keepdims` should work for you.  I don't know why `keepdims` is not in the online documentation.  Check the docstring in an interactive shell such as ipython.

Comment: Just checked it out, you are correct. It's there even though it's not documented. Thanks a lot! I'm assuming this will return multiple 1s in case there is more than one maximum?

Comment: Yes.  I was about to show another method that would select just the first occurrence of the maximum, but @Divakar beat me to it.

Comment: I decided to accept your answer anyway, as this property is not too important for my use case and I think your version is a bit easier to understand. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

In case of ties (two or more elements being the highest one in a row), where you want to select only one, here's one approach to do so with [`np.argmax`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html) and [`broadcasting`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.broadcasting.html) -

```
(A.argmax(1)[:,None] == np.arange(A.shape[1])).astype(int)
```

Sample run -

```
In [296]: A
Out[296]: 
array([[ 0.2,  0.3,  0.5],
       [ 0.5,  0.5,  0. ]])

In [297]: (A.argmax(1)[:,None] == np.arange(A.shape[1])).astype(int)
Out[297]: 
array([[0, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 0]])
```